# Flask App on Azure Stops Collecing Logs after app. 30 minutes

Tags: python-3.x, azure-web-app-service, flask-sqlalchemy, azure-appservice

I have built an Flask App hosted on Azure App Services. The app works well and I am capturing logs using the logging. The issue is that I can find the log file on kudu: /home/LogFiles as expected. But somehow entries are not collected as of some point. I know for a fact that the app is running. Any thoughts ? Code:

```
   log_file = f'{path}{formatted_datetime}-xxx_logging-log.log'
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
    
    file_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    logging.info('*** Logging Started')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you've added a handler but haven't explicitly set the logging level. By default, it's set to WARNING, which means INFO messages (like your 'Logging Started' message) may not be captured.

- Here below is my repro, I've made adjustments for the logger name, path handling, and introduced a `RotatingFileHandler` for log rotation. Adjust the `maxBytes` and `backupCount` parameters according to your requirements.

Here is the code: **config.py_file**

```py
import os
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

LOGS_DIR = 'logs'
os.makedirs(LOGS_DIR, exist_ok=True)

formatted_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
LOG_FILE = os.path.join(LOGS_DIR, f'{formatted_datetime}-app.log')

# Set up the logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Create a rotating file handler
file_handler = RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILE, maxBytes=1024 * 1024, backupCount=5)

# Set the formatter
file_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)

# Add the handler to the logger
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

# Flask-SQLAlchemy configuration
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'your_database_uri_here'
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

# Create a SQLAlchemy instance
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

Here I able to get the log entries at every point of time as expected.

[image]

Then I deployed it to my app service.

[image]

- Iam able to get the log entries in kudu: /home/Logs as expected.
  [image]

[image]

Here, the logs are collected even after 30 minutes.